# Geo tersm in Luis synonyms generating

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

I'm facing this issue with geo places. For example.
USA, United states, United states of America, US.
Luis is able to detect them as built in entity of geographyV2
but I want NLP to pass all the similar terms of the user input. Ex user said US we send back geographyV2 entity and the similar synonyms of it , can luis do that by any chance? I'm desperate for this

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you need and maybe provide some examples of your LUIS response payload? So if user says USA, what is LUIS giving you back as geographyV2 entity? And what is it you expect instead?

Comment: when I type USA it returns exactly what I expect.  entity of geographyV2 but what I want is further synonyms generating so USA equals US equals United states... etc. Cuz in the backend I have united states but user asked for USA . NLP Lus is detecting it correctly but it isn't exactly matching what I have in the DB of my App

Comment: So ultimately, you have a single country value you are expecting, and you want have LUIS return that value for all synonyms? E.g. for "United States", you always want that to be the value returned even if user enters US, USA, etc?

Comment: no I want the ability for synonms generating if its possible in Luis

Comment: Ah, ok so you are wanting the full list back? User says "USA" and you want to receive object with "USA, US, United States, etc."?

Comment: yes exactly . Can luis do that?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear this is possible using the built-in geographyv2 entity. The entity just returns the value that was entered and the category is belongs to (country/region, city, point of interest, etc.). If you use the verbose response it will also give you additional information such as the starting index and length. But I can't find any option to have it return all related values/alternate names.

- [GeographyV2 prebuilt entity for LUIS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-geographyv2?tabs=V3)

Even if you create a custom list entity in LUIS with a normalized value and synonyms, I don't think you can get the full list of synonyms for that entity, only the normalized value. So if you need to see a list of alternate spellings, you're going to need some other function or API. I did a brief search and there's not much out there. The best I found was [REST Countries](https://restcountries.eu/#api-endpoints-name), which you can pass a partial or alternate name in, and it will give you a bunch of information in the response. You may have to do some legwork, though, because it will give multiple matches (e.g. a [search for United States](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/united%20states) returns results for *United States of America* and *United States Minor Outlaying Islands*). This is as close as I can figure out on how to solve your issue.